# How can create abstract enum?

Tags: java, enums

my problems in the next, I have a component in java that get an Enum, but I need use that componente with a several ENUM these enum are related.

Then, I have two next ENUM

```
public enum Train{
    A, B, C
}

public enum Bus{
    L,U,V
}
```

The component get a ENUM, but I want can set both Train or Bus, depending on a precondition

If I select Bus set to component Bus Enum, if select Tran set Train enum

I tray with interface of the next mode:

```
public interface Transport(){}

public enum Bus implements Transport
publi enum Train implements Transport
```

But not work because the component call Enum mehtods, and only can set enum methods

I can't pass Enum as generic because I need some control about the parameter that I set in the component.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve what you want, using a generic type parameter `T` that extends both `Enum` and implements `Transport`:

```
interface Transport {}

enum Bus implements Transport {
    A, B, C
}

enum Train implements Transport {
    L, U, V
}

public class Test<T extends Enum & Transport> {
    private T transport;

    Test(T transport) {
        this.transport = transport;

        // Can still use enum methods
        System.out.println(this.transport.name());
        System.out.println(this.transport.ordinal());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(Train.L); // prints out "L", "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great approximation but I get the next error when inherit the component Bound mismatch: The type RepositoryModel.Nom is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum & Repos.Transport> of the type NomStringConverter<E>

Comment: I answered the question with the information you provided. I don't know what your other classes look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it like this,check at [jls-8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9),you will find below message

> Enum types (§8.9) must not be declared abstract; doing so will result
>   in a compile-time error.
>
> An enum type is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum
>   constant that has a class body.
>
> It is a compile-time error to explicitly declare an enum type to be
>   final.

Comment: Maybe it's not abstract, but I'm looking for a way to restrict a group of enums